# creating desktop exe application with node js code

Tags: node.js, exe, desktop-application

I have developed a `node js` dashboard which runs on localhost. Now I want to convert that dashboard to the desktop application file and installer so that whenever the client wants to use the dashboard there is no need to enter the url in browser he can just open the application and use the dashboard.

Is there any third party application for this conversion like we have EXE PHP output application like that

Comment: Did you think about using Electron.js?

Comment: yeah. But after installing the Electron.js. Can we import my project or we need write again. @Tzelon

Comment: assume your project is just a plain web server, you can program electron to simply start your server and have the electron browser windows open the url (e.g. localhost:3000)